# How do I combine local cache flow and flow from cloud API; and update local cache?

Tags: android, caching, kotlin-flow

I have a Room database as my local cache and I'm using firebase realtime database as the cloud database.

I would like to first get the data from the local cache and once the cloud data is received, save it in the local database and return it to the UI.  The cloud database is the single source of truth.

Here is the use case.

```
class ReadAllBooks(
    private val booksRepository: BooksRepository,
    private val firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase,
    private val databaseString: String
) {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<List<BookModel>> {

        val localFlow = booksRepository.getBooks()
        val bookRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(databaseString)
        val bookCloudFlow = bookRef.addListValueEventListenerFlow(BookModel::class.java)

        return localFlow.flatMapLatest { localData ->
            bookCloudFlow.onStart {
                emit(localData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function successfully returns the local cache data and then the cloud data once available.  The problem I'm having is trying to understand how to collect the data from the bookCloudFlow to save/update the local database.

If I write the return portion like this,

```
return bookCloudFlow.flatMapLatest { cloudData ->
     // Insert into local db cache
     bookRepository.insertOrUpdateBookList(cloudData)
     localFlow.onStart {
          emit(cloudData)
     }
}
```

and get the cloud data first and save it in the local cache, when there is no network connection no data is returned, even if there is data in the local cache.